# How to determine the order for a SRRC filter

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I want to make a SRRC filter using matlab function rcosdesign. But I don't know how to determine the order for a SRRC filter. the rcosdesign need rolloff factor, sps,span; the order=sps*span+1. But how to determine the order? Is there a algorithm？

I get some algorithm, such as Genetic Algorithm, Lagrangian Optimal Shaping Filter Design Method Based on Solving Matrix, but my tutor ask me why to choose this, I don't know how to reslove.